# NVIDIA SDK Manager fails to install on Jetson Xavier NX

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-jetson

I am working on Jetson Xavier NX development Kit, I am trying some deepstream-5.0 apps on it and I have to analyse the performance of Deepstream-5.0 sample apps and my custom app which is very much similar to similar-apps. So, to analyse the performance I want to use NVIDIA NSight Systems.

Now, to install NVIDIA NSight Systems using NVIDIA SDK Manager I am trying to install SDK Manager on the Xavier system using the steps given [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-sdk-manager). But it is giving the following problem:

```
sudo apt install ./sdkmanager_1.2.0-6738_amd64.deb

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'sdkmanager:amd64' instead of './sdkmanager_1.2.0-6738_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sdkmanager:amd64 : Depends: libgconf-2-4:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libcanberra-gtk-module:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: locales:amd64 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried installing the dependent libraries, updating and upgrading the system and fixing the broken packages but got no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving the error because the Xavier NX is an ARM system, and the Nvidia SDK Manager is meant for an amd64 instruction set. If you follow the flowchart on their page, you'll notice that the SDK Manager arrow points to a host system.

The solution is to run Ubuntu on a desktop or laptop, and hook up the Xavier NX over microUSB. Follow the instructions on the page you linked to update the dev board with the latest software.

Another important note: if you flash your development board using Nvidia's flash.sh script (the script tied to the flash button in the GUI) your partition will be limited to 14GB regardless of it's size. The workaround is to go into "/home//nvidia/nvidia_sdk/Jetpack_<version_number>_<dev_kit>/Linux_for_Tegra/tools" and run the script titled "jetson-disk-image-creator.sh"

The script creates a disk image you can write to an sd card using balena etcher, which doesn't have the partition limit.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. So, I tried updating and upgrading the packages on my system by running the following commands and it worked for me. Although I would like to mention that I am working on TX2, I am not sure about Xavier.

```
sudo apt update
apt list --upgradable
sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt install ./sdkmanager-[version].deb
```

Answer (score 0):

**sudo apt-get update**

will resolve this issue !